# GRUB not showing windows 8.1 already installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Actually there is a similar question on the community before as well but what I am facing is a different problem. Also there the person has not properly posted the status of his grub. Actually I installed windows 8.1 on my laptop & it was working fine. Then I installed Ubuntu on another partition & as per the instructions again booted using live usb of Ubuntu to repair GRUB using `boot repair`. You can find the [boot repair report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10391298) . But now the GRUB menu is not showing Windows option at all & I am unable to boot into Windows. Please help me - it's urgent!! Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Usually you have to select which OS to boot in your BIOS, under teh UEFI boot menu. Location varies by BIOS

Comment: Can you elaborate  a little more...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported - see the TROUBLESHOOTING section. In your case , the bios is selecting Ubuntu rather then windows. As i said it varies by BIOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 does not shut down properly by default. I suspect this is your problem.
In your code I see:

```
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
mount /dev/sda3 : Error code 14
mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
```

Try mounting as suggested and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Actually mount both sda1 and sda3

Comment: I am a new user - can you please tell me how to mount.

Comment: I tried to mount but it's showing the following message - "Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option."

Comment: Did you: mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option

Comment: Another option. And I'm not sure of the result. Is to completely power down - remove power supply and battery. The boot back to Ubuntu and try update-grub again

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to Carl for providing a hint - big hint. Actually my drives were not getting mounted even by using mount -r /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 but then I serached over net. I found out that my windows was not properly shutdown previous time, so the grub is showing trouble. So, I needed to manually mount the partitions & to achieve that I had to go to Disks tool in Ubuntu & follow the following steps as given in [this link](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/). Then, I went to GRUB configure(has to be downloaded) to set the display resolution to 680*480 minimum. Then grub starts showing Windows. Boot into windows, download appropriate display drivers & then get back to Ubuntu to set back Grub to its original resolution. Everytihng is okay now..

Answer (score -1):

Just type the following command in a terminal<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo update-grub
```